# como hago precarga de la data response con ajax

Tags: ajax

Hola porfavor podrian ayudarme explicando como hacer que la repuesta desde php se cargue primero antes de mostrarse al cliente, deseo que la carga al lado del cliente sea mas rapida y no se vea como.

php
`include ("conexion_bd.php");

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tarot ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 78");




while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $cartaNombre = $row["Carta"];

    echo "<input type='image' src='$cartaNombre' value='$cartaNombre' alt='no se encuentra' width='7%' class='cartas' name='carta' onclick='this.disabled = true; valor(value)'>";

}

mysqli_free_result($result);



mysqli_close($con);`
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "baraja.php",
            success: function(response)
        {
            $('.baraja').html(response).fadeIn();
        }

       });

muchas gracias
```

espero que me haga entender ayudenme porfavor

Comment: Sinceramente, pero no he entendido absolutamente nada de lo que pretendes hacer

Comment: deseo hacer una precarga del response antes que se muestre en index

Comment: pero que es "pre carga"? quizas un loader o algo asi?

Comment: Antes que se muestre que index? Que es lo que necesitas? contextualiza un poco. Ya que no se entiende

Comment: A ver, ¿pretendes que antes de que se cargue la página en el cliente recibir la respuesta de la consulta realizada por ajax? De ante mano te comunico que esto no es posible, de ser eso lo que pretendes deberías incluir un guión PHP en esa misma página para que te cargue los datos inicialmente y posteriormente mostrarlos en el cliente.

Comment: No necesariamente, puede hacer una llamada ajax con $(document).ready(); lo que hace que llama cuando la pagina esta totalmente cargada, y eso si es un dato pequeño, se logra en milésimas de segundos. Esta consulta a su propio controlador y retorna la respuesta para que la cargues. **Recuerda que PHP es un controlador, y se debe utilizar como tal** @Javi

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda Por supuesto que se puede hacer de ese modo, pero por muy poco tiempo que tarde en hacerlo eso lo sigue haciendo una vez ha sido cargada la página en el cliente, y por lo que entiendo de la pregunta de este usuario, lo quiere hacer en **pre-carga** y esto significa **antes** de la carga.

Comment: disculapa tienes razon voy editar la pregunta para que este mejor

Comment: Aun así no existe una precarga si estamos por el lado del cliente, siempre y cuando no se utilice el controlador como cliente. Sin embargo se puede hacer la llamada ajax y que el `<body>` este oculto, hasta que la llamada haya sido exitosa, y allí mostrar la pagina @Javi

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda no me has entendido bien sinceramente, a lo que me refiero con precarga NO me estoy refiriendo a que exista un método en concreto para hacer algo antes de la carga de la página, a lo que me refiero es cuando tú cargas por ejemplo la página **www.tusitio.es/index.php** el código **PHP** en esa página se está ejecutando **antes** de que se haya cargado ningún contenido en el cliente. Espero que ahora lo entiendas!

Comment: Lo entiendo. Lo que digo es que **"No existe pre-carga de página si direccionas a un archivo por el lado del cliente, y no estés usando un controlador como tal"**

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que necesitas es hacer es cargar esas imagenes y luego manipularlas con javascript. te aconsejo hacer lo siguiente.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var respuesta='';
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "baraja.php",
            async: false,//Esto hace que deba esperar esta peticion para proseguir

            success: function(response)
        {
            respuesta=response;
            $('.baraja').html(response).fadeIn();
        }

       });

    //Aqui todo el codigo que se debe ejecutar despues de la peticion
    //se puede manipular la respuesta a a gusto y antojo

} );
```